# adding a page break to an email to fix outlook 2007 bug

Tags: html, email, outlook-2007

I am building quite a large html email. Outlook adds a random white space break near the bottom. Ive read that outlook 2007 uses word to render emails and if an email is a certain length it will force a page break in somewhere. there seems to be no work around for this. If i could add this page break in myself earlier in the email i could avoid outlook adding this in page break in an area i dont want it to. Is there a way to add a break break through the html?

Answer (score 0):

[Force page break in HTML/ASP when opening and printing multiple records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752560/force-page-break-in-html-asp-when-opening-and-printing-multiple-records)