# Force page break in HTML/ASP when opening and printing multiple records

Tags: asp.net, html, css

So I have a repeater control that lists a bunch of information for each staff member...one after another.  Problem is when I try to print this list I have staff records starting out in the middle of the page.  **I would like to solve this issue by forcing a page break at the beginning or end of each record/repeater item.**  How can I accomplish this?

If it's any help, this is the structure of the page:

```
<body>
     <form>
          <asp:repeater> 
               <itemtemplate>
                    <table> 
                       <bunch of html>
                       </bunch of html>
                    </table>
               </itemtemplate>
          </asp:repeater>
     </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Place the following code in the HEAD of the html:

```
<STYLE TYPE='text/css'>
P.pagebreakhere {page-break-before: always}
</STYLE>
```

Then place the following code in the BODY of the html where you want the pagebreak:

```
<P CLASS="pagebreakhere">
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `page-break-before` and `page-break-after` CSS rules.

See [page breaks](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html#propdef-page-break-after) on the CSS 2.1 spec.

Answer (score 2):

Look into `page-break-before` and `page-break-after` css declarations